# difference normal quote and backquote in python

Tags: python

If i write

```
a=eval('[[0]*2]*2')
a[0][0]=1
```

`a` would become `[[1,0],[1,0]]`

If I write

```
a=eval(`[[0]*2]*2`)
a[0][0]=1
```

`a` would become `[[1,0],[0,0]]`

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> '[[0]*2]*2'
'[[0]*2]*2'

>>> `[[0]*2]*2`
'[[0, 0], [0, 0]]'
```

The first one is text, the second evaluates immediately into data structure and returns its text representation `'[[0, 0], [0, 0]]'`.

The problem with `[[0]*2]*2` is that this evaluates to a list of references to the same object. That's why you get `[[1,0],[1,0]]` and not `[[1,0],[0,0]]`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this backquote syntax has been removed from Python 3. Use `repr()` instead.

Comment: It is impornat mentioning that "backquotes" are no quotes at all in Python - they are jsut the equivalent of a call to "repr" - but whatever is inside then is "live code" that is executed. Yes, this is weird, and it has been removed in newer version. One should avoid using backquotes.

Answer (score 5):

```
eval('[[0]*2]*2')
```

This creates the result of evaluating the Python code `[[0]*2]*2`. Multiplying a list makes a list with several references to the original objects. The resulting list is `[x, x]`, where each `x` is a list that looks like `[0, 0]`. Modifying one of the sublists modifies both, because they are the same object.

```
eval(`[[0]*2]*2`)
```

This creates the above (via the inner `[[0]*2]*2`), then creates its string representation (because of the backticks), which is `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`, then creates the result of evaluating that as Python code. This time, the two sublists are separate lists that each look like `[0, 0]`, but are separate objects. Modifying one of them has no effect on the other, because they are not the same object.

BTW, using ``` `` ``` has been strongly discouraged for many years. You **can't actually quote things** with ``` `` ```. It's used to create the string representation of some Python object.

```
`hi mom`
```

is a syntax error.